# WPF No NameScope found to register the Name

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create a "debug" TextBlock, in the sense it is just like a MessageBox, but doesn't interrupt like it. Rather, it is like a statusbar, which gives output information silently. Here is my current code

```
private void Debug(string data)
    {
        TextBlock tb = componentContainer.FindName("Debugbox") as TextBlock;
        if (tb == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("yo");
            tb = new TextBlock() {Foreground = Brushes.Orange };
            if (NameScope.GetNameScope(tb) == null)
                NameScope.SetNameScope(tb, new NameScope());
            componentContainer.RegisterName("Debugbox", tb);
            componentContainer.Children.Add(tb);
        }
        tb.Text = data;
    }
```

However, it is giving me "No NameScope found to register the Name". I tried replacing

```
componentContainer.RegisterName("Debugbox", tb);
```

with

```
Namescope.GetNameScope(tb).RegisterName("Debugbox", tb);
```

and it works well. But if this function is used multiple times, the TextBlock is simply overwritten which makes the required output hard to see.

NOTE : componentContainer is a Canvas

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Or is there any better way to do something similar?

Comment: You're making everytime a new instance of tb  "tb = new TextBlock()" that's why it is overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply keep the TextBlock instance in a private field:

```
private TextBlock debugBox;

private void Debug(string data)
{
    if (debugBox == null)
    {
        debugBox = new TextBlock { Foreground = Brushes.Orange };
        componentContainer.Children.Add(debugBox);
    }
    debugBox.Text = data;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's perfect! Didn't think of it before. Really, thanks!